# What does "tight space" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am not sure about the meaning of the word "tight space" in the following sentence in a game's description:

> When hungry fishes loom over, tight spaces can be your lifesaver.

The virtual game lets you experience the journey of a fish in deep water.

Please help me confirm which of the following meanings of the word "tight" fits here:

> 1. Fixed or fastened firmly in place: a tight lid; tight screws; a tight knot.
> 2. Stretched or drawn out fully: a tight wire; a tight drumhead.
> 3. Of such close construction as to be impermeable: cloth tight enough to hold water; warm in our tight little cabin.
> 4. a. Leaving little empty space through compression; compact: a tight suitcase; a tight weave. b. Affording little spare time; full: a tight
>      schedule.
> 5. Closely reasoned or concise: a tight argument; a tight style of writing.
> 6. Fitting close or too close to the skin; snug: a tight collar; a fit that was much too tight.
> 7. Slang Personally close; intimate: "me and the D.A., who happen to be very tight with one another" (Tom Wolfe).
> 8. Experiencing a feeling of constriction: a tight feeling in the chest.
> 9. Reluctant to spend or give; stingy.
> 10. a. Obtainable with difficulty or only at a high price: tight money. b. Affected by scarcity: a tight market.
> 11. Difficult to deal with or get out of: a tight spot.
> 12. Barely profitable: a tight bargain.
> 13. Closely contested; close: a tight match.
> 14. Chiefly British Neat and trim in appearance or arrangement.
> 15. Marked by full control over elements or subordinates; firm: tight management; a tight orchestral performance.
> 16. Slang Intoxicated; drunk.
> 17. Baseball Inside.

Comment: I think 6. is the most accurate choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear: in this game, *you* are the fish?  And the object is to hide from other, larger fish?

If that's the case, then none of your definitions seem to fit very well.  You might try a different dictionary, such as Oxford Living English:

> [**tight**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tight) (adj): 3. *(of an area or space)* having or allowing little room for manoeuvre.

In this case, "tight" refers to a small enough space that you can get in, but the larger fish can not.